# Numpy meshgrid from unordered x, y, z data

Tags: python, numpy

I have x, y and z data which looks like the following (sample data):

```
x_data = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4]
y_data = [16, 64, 32, 64, 32, 16, 16, 32, 64, 32, 16, 64]
z_data = [64, 31, 29, 78, 72, 63, 93, 40, 54, 35, 44, 3]
```

Since I can map every z value to an unique x/y data pair, I would like to plot it as a filled countour plot in matplotlib.    `contourf`    requires x and y to be either meshgrids or to be the size of the corresponding dimension of z.

At the moment the code I use to prepare the data is the following:

```
mesh_x, mesh_y = np.meshgrid(np.unique(x_data), np.unique(y_data))
mesh_z = np.zeros(mesh_x.shape)

for x, y, z in zip(x_data, y_data, z_data):
    mesh_z[np.bitwise_and(y == mesh_y, x == mesh_x)] = z
```

Since `np.unique` reorders the values, I can not use `np.reshape(z_data, mesh_x.shape)` to create the needed data structure.

Although this solution works, I feel like there must be a better way to archieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.asarray([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4])
y_data = np.asarray([16, 64, 32, 64, 32, 16, 16, 32, 64, 32, 16, 64])
z_data = np.asarray([64, 31, 29, 78, 72, 63, 93, 40, 54, 35, 44, 3])
# Sort coordinates and reshape in grid
idx = np.lexsort((y_data, x_data)).reshape(4, 3)
# Plot
plt.contourf(x_data[idx], y_data[idx], z_data[idx])
```

Output:

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Good idea. Not faster in my test scenario, but a little more direct (at least code wise). Generally speaking, is this a better solution?

Comment: @Lenwo Well I think it should be faster for big inputs, although that may not be too important unless you really have very big data. Personally I find it clearer this way, but honestly you should probably go with what you find more readable and easier to understand when you have to come back to it in the future (usually plotting code is not really performance-critical, and the ability to tweak and fix the images is more important than which solution is the "most optimal").