# Incorrect mapping in matplotlib

Tags: excel, matplotlib, heatmap, reshape

I have some issues with this code.
I would like to plot an heatmap by using some x and y data that are given and stored in 1 excel file, and the z data which I had to extract into another excel file.

The resulting plot has however alternating correct and incorrect rows, thus for this map that should have a bright feature from bottom left to top right, the result is actually an "x" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJsi1.png)

These are the part of the coordinates, just as an example (they basically start from the left-to-right until the end of the row and then right-to-left while moving up) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfH6s.png).

You can then see how the plot is supposed to look like (you can use the dark blue and red spots on the bottom left as reference) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whUe6.png).

I do not understand why it does not follow the same order of the values in the excel file as each row in the spreadsheet refers to the right point.

Thank you for your time

```
pathxy=(r'C:\Users\goofy\OneDrive\PhD\Results\No of measured data point.xlsx')
xy_df = pd.read_excel(pathxy)
x = xy_df['x'].values
y = xy_df['y'].values
data=min_df['Ec'].values

n = int(np.sqrt(len(data)))
zz = np.reshape(data, (n, n))
plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.ylim(y.min(), y.max())

plt.imshow(zz, cmap='viridis', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.max(), y.min()])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[Partial dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfH6s.png)

[Incorrect plot from python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJsi1.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whUe6.png)

Comment: You are right, one row is OK the other one is NG.  Look at YOUR DATA: first x is 7→21, next is 21→7, and again 7→21, 21→7, etc, I GUESS that you must reverse the odd rows, more or less like `for row in z[1::2]: row = row[::-1]`

Comment: But if x and y are coordinates, I thought this wouldn't require any data manipulation

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437559/numpy-meshgrid-from-unordered-x-y-z-data

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on a comment of mine

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nrow = 10; ncol = 8
fig, (ng, ok) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(ncol, nrow/2), layout='tight')

# x, y arrays
# make x as in your excel ፨ that is, boustrophedon ፨
x = np.concatenate([np.arange(ncol)[::i] for i in [1, -1]*(nrow//2)])
y = np.concatenate([[i]*ncol for i in range(nrow)])

# a simple function of x, y - reshaped appropriately for imshow
z = (x+y).reshape(nrow, ncol)

ng.imshow(z, origin='lower')
ng.set_title('''\
It's not what I thought and it's not what I pictured
When I was imagining my zed''', fontsize='small') # youtu.be/xE-A0cNSLmc?t=34

# reorder z to have imshow pleased
for row in z[1::2]: row[::] = row[::-1]

ok.imshow(z, origin='lower')
ok.set_title('… but this is it', fontsize='small')

plt.show()
```